# Delete selected notebook tab with button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

whats the function for deleting selected notebook tab in tkinter?
I couldn't find anything about this on the web?

This is the code that I wrote, i only need function:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
import sys

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")
myApp.geometry("1000x1200")

tasktabs=ttk.Notebook(myApp)

TabOne=ttk.Frame(tasktabs)
tasktabs.add(TabOne,text="Tab One")

TabOne=ttk.Frame(tasktabs)
tasktabs.add(TabOne,text="Tab Two")

def deletetab():

    # whats the function for deleting tab?

    pass

DelButton=Button(myApp,text=' Delete  ', command=deletetab)
DelButton.grid(row=0,column=3, sticky="W")


tasktabs.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def deletetab():
    tasktabs.forget(tasktabs.select())
```

deletes the currently selected tab.

Comment: Thanks my friend, please , if you can help me with this also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199402/binding-function-to-treeview-does-not-work-tkinter

Comment: It's important to mention that `forget` doesn't _delete_ the tab, it just removes it from view.

Comment: @Bryan: Is it possible to delete it. I tried with `.destroy()` but the object seems to still be there..

Comment: Yes, it's possible to delete it. Unfortunately, `tasktabs.select()` returns the _name_ of the widget rather than the actual frame widget, and you need a reference to the widget to destroy it.

Comment: I was confused because I tried to destroy with the correct reference but when I printed the ref it still existed. But when I printed `winfo_children()` it was gone. Thanks anyway, and now I've found five ways of getting a widget reference.

Answer (score 4):

As rightly pointed by @Bryan Oakley, the above accepted answer doesn't actually "delete" the selected notebook, the object still exists but hidden from the view.

To actually delete the tab, call the *.destroy()* method on the child as below:

```
def deletetab():
    for item in tasktabs.winfo_children():
        if str(item)==tasktabs.select():
            item.destroy()       
            return  #Necessary to break or for loop can destroy all the tabs when first tab is deleted
```

This technique worked for me. Here's a complete sample code to test it out:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def deletetab():
    for item in nb.winfo_children():
        if str(item) == (nb.select()):
            item.destroy()
            return  #Necessary to break or for loop can destroy all the tabs when first tab is deleted

root = Tk()

button = ttk.Button(root,text='Delete Tab', command=deletetab)
button.pack()

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack()

f1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
f2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
f3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
f4 = ttk.Frame(nb)
f5 = ttk.Frame(nb)

nb.add(f1, text='FRAME_1')
nb.add(f2, text='FRAME_2')
nb.add(f3, text='FRAME_3')
nb.add(f4, text='FRAME_4')
nb.add(f5, text='FRAME_5')

root.mainloop()
```