# Add new frame by Checkbox (Tkinter)

Tags: tkinter

I try to create a GUI in python and need your help.
In this GUI, the user should optimize his results through a choice of options. I wrote the following code:

```
'''----------------frame Discharge calculation-------------------'''
self.discharge = BooleanVar()
self.discharge.set(False)
self.dischargeBut = Checkbutton(frame, text = "calculate discharge", variable = self.discharge)
self.dischargeBut.place(x=600, y=40)

frame3 = Frame(note)
note.add(frame3, text = "Discharge calculation")
self.xButton = 370
self.xText = 250
self.xText2 = 350
self.yAddText = 10
self.yAddText2 = 10
```

The Problem is that frame3 should only be visible / active when the Checkbox ("calculate discharge") is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a widget visible by use of any of the geometry mangers: pack, grid & place. All of these can also unmap a widget so it's not rendered. The easiest way i think would to associate the checkbutton with a callback function which displays or removes the widget.

Be careful though as mapping and unmapping widgets can cause the containing widget to change it's size.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

'''----------------frame Discharge calculation-------------------'''
discharge = BooleanVar()
discharge.set(False)

def display_calc():
    if discharge.get() == True:
        frame3.place(x=60, y=100)
    else:
        frame3.place_forget()

dischargeBut = Checkbutton(root, text="calculate discharge",
                           variable=discharge, command=display_calc)
dischargeBut.place(x=60, y=40)

# The Discharge calculation widget
frame3 = Frame(root)
Label(frame3, text='Discharge calculation').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also; using `place()` is almost always a bad choice. Read about `grid()` and `pack()` as they are easier to use when your GUI becomes more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. It work perfectly. May you have an idea how to make this as a tab. So to make a tab visible. I have to many option for the calculation and the overview of this GUI is very bad.

Comment: Please start a new question for follow up questions.

Comment: I got it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242961/delete-selected-notebook-tab-with-button-tkinter Thanks anyway :)