# How is Tkinter handling lambda after binding event?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am trying to write some code that will send the value of an `Entry` box to a function based on a binding. I can technically get the behavior I want in the code below, but I'm a) not sure why it works and b) am quite sure I am not doing this in the most pythonic way. I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding the `event` or `lambda` or both.

In the code below the `Entry` box called `input_box1` when the binding triggers, the `inp_var1.get()` code only gets the default value, not anything that has been entered into the box. In other words, the `test1` function will print...

> Test1 Foo

... no matter what you type into the entry.

The binding on `input_box2` works exactly as I expect. I type anything in there and click somewhere else and it prints the new entry. However I don't understand why my `lambda` doesn't want an `event` or why I need to repeat the `inp_var2.get()` call.

If anyone knows what's going under the hood I'd love to hear it! Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def test1(event, i):
    print('Test1', i)

def test2(event, i):
    print('Test2', i)

root = Tk()
title_label = Label(root, text='This does not work!')
title_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

inp_var1 = StringVar(value='Foo')
input_box1 = Entry(root, textvariable=inp_var1)
input_box1.grid(column=0, row=1)

inp_var2 = StringVar(value='Bar')
input_box2 = Entry(root, textvariable=inp_var2)
input_box2.grid(column=0, row=2)

input_box1.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, i=inp_var1.get(): test1(event, i))
input_box2.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda i=inp_var2.get(): test2(i, inp_var2.get()))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated *once*, when the function was originally defined: that's when `input_var1.get()` is being called, which is far too early for there to be any contents to get.  The `i=inp_var2.get()` in your second example is irrelevant, as that parameter is always overriden by the `event` parameter passed to all event bindings.

Comment: I'm not tracking, sorry. I need to `get()` inp_var2 somehow or else I don't see how my function will get the input from the user?

Comment: The `inp_var2.get()` that's actually inside the lambda, and therefore executes at the time that it is called, is what's getting the input.  It should probably be written as `lambda event: test2(event, inp_var2.get())` - or perhaps don't pass `event` to `test2()`, as it doesn't use that parameter anyway.

Comment: Or you could just do `input_box2.bind('<FocusOut>', test2)`, and do the `.get()` inside `test2()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has very little to do with Tkinter itself.  It's also not so much connected to `lambda` as it is to Python in general.

Take both of those out of the equation, and consider the following Python program:

```
def f(x=3, y=4):
    print('x =', x, 'y =', y)

f(0, 0)
f(0)
f()
```

Assuming Python 3 (or `from __future__ import print_function`), when run, this prints:

```
x = 0 y = 0
x = 0 y = 4
x = 3 y = 4
```

That's because the *first* call to `f` passes `0, 0`, so `x` and `y` are both bound to zero.  The *second* call to `f` passes just `0` so `x` is bound to `0` and `y` is bound to its default value of 4.  The *third* call passes nothing at all and `x` and `y` are both bound to their default values.

(So far, this should all be clear enough.)

Now let's fuss with this a bit.  I'll continue to assume Python 3 so that `input` means what in Python 2 we have to use `raw_input` to achieve:

```
def f(x=input('enter default x: '), y=input('enter default y: ')):
    print('x =', x, 'y =', y)

print('about to call f three times')
f(0, 0)
f(0)
f()
```

Before you run this sample program, think about what you expect it to do.  Then run it—here's my result:

```
$ python3 t.py
enter default x: hello
enter default y: world
about to call f three times
x = 0 y = 0
x = 0 y = world
x = hello y = world
```

Why did this read the default values for `x` and `y` *before* we even called it the first time?  Why *didn't* it read new default values for `x` and `y` on each call?

#### Think about that for a bit, then read on

Really, do that.  Ask *why* the inputs happened at these odd times.

#### Now that you've thought about it...

It *did* do that, though.  That's the key here.  The *default* values for your arguments are captured *at the time the `def` statement is executed*.  The `def` statement, which binds the name `f` to our function, is actually *run* when Python loads the file, after seeing the body of the function.  The function itself is run later, after Python has gotten to the `print` call and then to the first `f` call.

A `lambda` in Python is just a sort of anonymous function definition.  Instead of:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

we can write:

```
square = lambda x: x * x
```

The `lambda` expression defines a new function-like item, a *lambda function*—you can't use `if`/`else` type statements inside one of these, just expressions, and they automatically return the value of their expression.  In this case our lambda function has one argument named `x`.  The function returns `x * x`.

The outer assignment, `square =`, binds this lambda function to the name `square`, just as if we'd done `def square(x)` instead.  So it's mostly just a syntactic trick: we can have a real function, like `square`, with arguments, or a limited lambda function that can only use expressions, like this anonymous function that we almost immediately bind to the name `square`.

The arguments part works the same either way though.  Just as with `f` and `input`, if we bind `x`:

```
square = lambda x=3: x * x
```

or:

```
square = lambda x=int(input('choose a default for x now> ')): x * x
```

that happens just *once*, when the `lambda` expression itself executes.  The *function* now has a variable `x` with a default value.

When, later, we *call* the function, we can provide a value for `x`, or let it default.  If we don't provide a value, Python uses the default that it captured *earlier*, when we executed the line with `lambda` in it, rather than now, when we call the lambda function.

This all holds for Tkinter as well.  You wrote:

```
input_box2.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda i=inp_var2.get(): test2(i, inp_var2.get()))
```

but that's pretty much the same as writing:

```
def f(i=inp_var2.get()):
    test2(i, inp_var2.get())

input_box2.bind('<FocusOut>', f)
```

except that you don't have to come up with the function-name `f` here.  The lambda variant of the function has no name, but it's still just a function.  (For that matter, when we do `square = lambda ...`, the lambda function doesn't have a name.  The name `square` is the name of a variable, not the name of the function.  The variable is merely *bound to* the function, so that `square(10)` calls it.)

Anyway, *later*, when Tkinter has an event that matches `<FocusOut>`, Tkinter calls `f` ... or, if you used `lambda`, calls your unnamed lambda function.  Tkinter provides one argument to that function; the one argument it provides is the event.  So your default value for `i` in `f` above is irrelevant—you could do:

```
def f(i=None):
    test2(i, inp_var2.get())
```

or:

```
def f(i='hello world'):
    test2(i, inp_var2.get())
```

because when Tkinter calls `f`, it always provides an actual argument for `i`.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. You laid it all out well. I felt like each step was stuff I knew but wasn't putting together the whole. In my longer project I have many of these binding-style events with functions that do similar things. I was trying to avoid having to greatly increase the number of functions I have by creating lambdas in this way, but maybe that wasn't meant to be!

Answer (score 0):

Since lambda is a no name function so we no need to write the two functions test1 and test2. I edited your program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
title_label = Label(root, text='This does not work!')
title_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

inp_var1 = StringVar(value='Foo')
input_box1 = Entry(root, textvariable=inp_var1)
input_box1.grid(column=0, row=1)

inp_var2 = StringVar(value='Bar')
input_box2 = Entry(root, textvariable=inp_var2)
input_box2.grid(column=0, row=2)

input_box1.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, i=inp_var1: print(i.get()))
input_box2.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, i=inp_var2: print(i.get()))

root.mainloop()
```