# How to make a variable number of buttons in Python tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I want to program a file explorer in Python 3.8.2 with tkinter. Everything  works fine except the buttons, because they just don't do  what they should.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

buttonlist = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
Buttons = []

root = tk.Tk()

for h, button in enumerate(buttonlist):
    Buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text=button, command = lambda : print(button)))
    Buttons[h].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But it doesn't matter which button I press, it always prints `button3`.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda will use the last value from the for-loop. You can force lambda to use the value of button at the button cretaion by supplying it as a default value:

```
lambda b=button: print(b)
```

More explanation in [How is Tkinter handling lambda after binding event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093502/how-is-tkinter-handling-lambda-after-binding-event)